# Restrict click event after link insertion

Tags: jquery

After dynamically inserting a link as follows:

```
$('#p_id').html('<a class="edit">Link</a>');
```

the following click event gets triggered:

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
    alert('I only want this event to be triggered on user interaction, NOT on creation.');
});
```

What is the solution to only have this event triggered when a user is actually clicking on the link, not when it is dynamically created?

Comment: event is not fired when element is added to the DOM, your issue is somewhere else

Comment: This behavior sounds odd.  Appending html will not trigger a click event.

Comment: i can't seem to reproduce your issue http://jsfiddle.net/8NWRb/ . can you explain when you trigger the link insertion? or reproduce your issue yourself in a fiddle?

Comment: is this inside ready?

Comment: can you clarify please ....

Comment: Thank you for all comments. Link insertion is triggered from a Bootstrap modal with the same class name. That explains everything. Feeling soooo stupid :-( Sorry for waisting your time :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for dynamically created elements , you can use `on` delegated event

```
 $('#p_id').on('click','.edit',function(){
    alert('I only want this event to be triggered on user interaction, NOT on creation.');
 });
```

> solution to only have this event triggered when a user is actually clicking on the link, not when it is dynamically created

**the click event is fired only when someone clicks on the selector element.. doesnot matter if it is dynamically created or not. it won't trigger by itself.. unless you use `trigger()`**

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$('#p_id').on('click', '.edit', function(){
    alert('I only want this event to be triggered on user interaction, NOT on creation.');
});
```

This notation allows to modifying parent's content.

Answer (score 0):

```
.click(function() {})
```

is just a shortcut for

```
.on('click', function() {})
```

so your code should work anyway.
Could it be that you are making a call to

```
$('.edit').click()  // <-- without arguments!
```

somewhere? This kind of notation triggers a click event.

Comment: is that an answer or a clarification ?

Comment: A hint to look further in his code, if he finds out that line in the code, to remove it could be the answer he looked for.